# codeigniter explode undefined offset

Tags: php, codeigniter, explode

i have models like this

```
  function getlastval($prefix,$namatable, $namafield)
{
    $this->db->order_by($namafield,'DESC');
    $key = $this->db->get($namatable);

    if($key->num_rows()>0)
    {

        $lastval= $key->row()->Kode_Material_Jasa;
        $lastval = explode($prefix,$lastval);
        $lv = $lastval[1]; //line 18 refer to this line
        //return ltrim($lv, '0');
        }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

function gencode($prefix, $digit, $lastval)
{
    return $prefix . str_pad($lastval+1, $digit, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

it works on the earlier controller

```
function addkategorimaterial()
{
    $this->load->model('m_admin');
    $lastval = $this->m_admin->getlastval('KKMJ','ms_kategori_material','Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa');
    $data['nextval'] = $this->m_admin->gencode('KKMJ',3,$lastval); 
    $data['title'] = 'QB Tambah Kategori Material';
    $this->load->view('head',$data);
    $this->load->view('content/add_kategori_material');
}
```

it returns `KKMJ001` but then its not working on the other controller

```
     $this->load->model('m_admin');
$lastval = $this->m_admin->getlastval('KMJ','ms_material_jasa','Kode_Material_Jasa');
    $data['nextval'] = $this->m_admin->gencode('KMJ',3,$lastval); 
    $data['kkmj']='';
    $data['title'] = 'QB Tambah Material / Jasa';

    print_r($data['nextval']);
    print_r($lastval);
```

so the function would return `KMJ001` and the error goes like this

[image]

how do i resolve this ?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post what line 18 is in your file.  Thanks.

Comment: @EricLeroy I'm guessing it's `$lv = $lastval[1];`

Comment: I am assuming line 18 is this: $lv = $lastval[1];

Comment: I'm guessing your `Kode_Material_Jasa` property in the failing instance does not contain the string `KMJ` so `explode()` is only returning a single-item array (no `1` index)

Comment: @jeffrey so $lastval will be contained the value on `Kode_Material_Jasa` field on the database, and the $lastval is i want to split them by the delimiter `$prefix` that attached into `$lastval`

Comment: What does `print_r($lastval);` give?

Comment: @phil so i need to enter 1 record first to the database ?

Comment: @raidenace $lastval doesn't produce anything, then i try `print_r($data['nextval']);` it returns 'KMJ001' just like i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `explode()` is the function you're after. The `explode()` function splits a string into an array by a delimiter.

It doesn't take a 'prefix' as it's first parameter as you've chosen (semantically). It takes the delimiter as it's first parameter.

Since you're passing `KMMJ` as the delimiter, the only way that you're going to get an array index of 1 is if the string returned from `$key->row()->Kode_Material_Jasa;` is something like: `fooKMMJbar`, which would produce: `array('foo', 'bar')` ...which is highly improbable.

Anyway, you've called `getlastval('KMJ'...)` and `getlastval('KMMJ'...)`, you sure they shouldn't be the same?